# Spark Java- reading gzip files from S3 ,mapToPair - takes a while to complete

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading .gz files from s3 file 1(5GB) file2(1GB). The job takes a around and hour and when completed the driver node status is shown as running.

while reading the file with the below code

```
sc.textfile(".gz").mapToPair(..mapping to an object)
```

The above takes about an hour.

```
sc.textfile(".gz").repartition(500).mapToPair(..mapping to an object) and
sc.textfile(".gz").repartition(500).mapToPair(..mapping to an object).partitionByKey((new HashPartitioner(500))
```

The above takes the same amount of time.

I do a spark submit with below

```
--driver-memory  10G --num-executors 17 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 19G
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you observe multiple executors running concurrently in the second case?

Comment: Just did a count on the RDD for the second case while reading a 5G file and dont see any activity in the executors tab on the UI. Interesting.

Comment: Check the master and deployment modes in your spark-submit invocation. Make sure you're not overriding these within your code.

Comment: No, I am not passing the master to the code in cluster mode. The only thing i set in my conf is below   `set("spark.io.compression.codec", "lzf")
                        .set("spark.speculation", "true")
                        .set("spark.cleaner.ttl", "10000")
                        .set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-XX:+UseG1GC");`

Comment: and weird part is the application is taking a lot of memory and spinning up additional EC2 instances with autoscaling  and the mapToPair part takes a lot of time..i have a picture of my executors but dont think i can post here.

Comment: Taking a lot of memory-- on the driver / executor(s)?

Comment: the executors and my drivers memory is at almost at max below is my spark-submit `./bin/spark-submit  --deploy-mode cluster --class com.mainclass  --driver-memory  20G --num-executors 17 --executor-cores 5 --executor-memory 19G --master spark://ip-***`